# Is there a way to access Tooling API METADATA objects without granting “View Setup and Configuration“ permission?

Tags: metadata, tooling-api

When trying to access METADATA (Setup) objects (such as FieldSet, Layout, ValidationRule, WorkflowRule, etc.) via Tooling API, without granting “View Setup and Configuration“ permission get the below error:

```
Error: INVALID_TYPE : sObject type 'FieldSet' is not supported.
```

**So is there a way to access Tooling API METADATA objects without granting “View Setup and Configuration“ permission?**

Strangely, for the Flow and process builder (metadata objects), it’s not giving an error, even when I tried accessing the same via tooling API query like others.

Comment: This feels related to the loss of Session ID usage for API access issue for partners...? I'm doubting there is an alternative but will watch with interest.

Comment: Might be. Waiting for the experts to pour some knowledge on this issue.

Comment: Raised case with SF technical support, which involved the Product team and got this update: there's no current way/workaround to access Tooling API METADATA objects without granting “View Setup and Configuration“ permission. That's disheartening to hear.